# opencv facerecognition: subspaceproject and subspacereconstruct methods in python

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I have searched through the web, but haven't found any answer so far to the following question, therefore I want to ask here if someone could help me out with that:

basically what i need is the same as in the solution from PraveenofPersia/Jesse there, but only the python implementation considering a Fisherface Recognizer:
[Any tips on confidence score for face verification (as opposed to face recognition)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757149/any-tips-on-confidence-score-for-face-verification-as-opposed-to-face-recogniti)

up to now I am facing the problem, that cv2 does not offer either subspaceProject nor any other.

has anyone suggestions here?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

those functions are unfortunately not exposed to the python api by default.

if you're building the cv2.pyd from source, there's an easy remedy :

- locate their resp. declarations, opencv/modules/contrib/include/opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp
- change `CV_EXPORTS Mat subspaceProject(...)` to  `CV_EXPORTS_W Mat subspaceProject(...)`
- change `CV_EXPORTS Mat subspaceReconstruct(...)` to  `CV_EXPORTS_W Mat subspaceReconstruct(...)`
- rerun cmake / make to rebuild the cv libs and the python wrapper module

thew additional _W prefix will add those functions to the generated wrappers

Comment: thank you berak, for your immediate support. I am unfortunately using the precompiled opencv and am not building it from source. is there any other workaround to not have to build from source? e.g. implementing in python what the two methods do (unfortunately cannot see what they do)?

Comment: ah, ok. i see. well, the src code for both is [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/contrib/src/lda.cpp#L174)

Comment: thank you!! :-) that's great. 

just one more question here: how would i solve the issue using your first suggestion? 
i am using windows 7 64bit and i have used the exe-installer for opencv. i have now downloaded the tar.gz. is there any possibility (how?) to e.g. build the cv2.pyd from source considering your adjustments of the contrib.hpp file and then somehow get a cv2.pyd file and could that simply be replaced with the current cv2.pyd? how would that work? is there any walkthrough somewhere available? or is that totally wrong approach..?

Comment: oh, no need to dl the code again, but ok. you need to run cmake, or cmake-gui, this will generate the cvproj/sln files for vs, then rebuild opencv. running the INSTALL project will copy the new cv2.pyd to your python folder ( you can do that manually, too)

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#installation-by-making-your-own-libraries-from-the-source-files

Comment: when building the opencv with the modified contrib.hpp file i keep ending up with the following error: 

`Linking CXX shared library ..\..\lib\cv2.pyd
Creating library file: ..\..\lib\libcv2.dll.a
CMakeFiles\opencv_python.dir/objects.a(cv2.cpp.obj):cv2.cpp:(.text$initcv2+0x120
b): undefined reference to `__imp_Py_InitModule4'
`collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [lib/cv2.pyd] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2`

any ideas for that?
using mingw, not vs.

Comment: hmm. unfortunately im not good with mingw. but sounds like a conflict [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp#L1338)  are you using python 27 or 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

I went ahead and re-wrote the functions in C++ as python.  It's not the cleanest, but it works!  If you take this python code and couple it with the high level concepts from  [another C++ example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757149/any-tips-on-confidence-score-for-face-verification-as-opposed-to-face-recogniti) you can do exactly what you're trying to do.

```
 # projects samples into the LDA subspace
 def subspace_project(eigenvectors_column, mean, source):
     source_rows = len(source)
     source_cols = len(source[0])

     if len(eigenvectors_column) != source_cols * source_rows:
         raise Exception("wrong shape")

     flattened_source = []
     for row in source:
         flattened_source += [float(num) for num in row]
     flattened_source = np.asarray(flattened_source)
     delta_from_mean = cv2.subtract(flattened_source, mean)
     # flatten the matrix then convert to 1 row by many columns
     delta_from_mean = np.asarray([np.hstack(delta_from_mean)])

     empty_mat = np.array(eigenvectors_column, copy=True)  # this is required for the function call but unused
     result = cv2.gemm(delta_from_mean, eigenvectors_column, 1.0, empty_mat, 0.0)
     return result


 # reconstructs projections from the LDA subspace
 def subspace_reconstruct(eigenvectors_column, mean, projection, image_width, image_height):
     if len(eigenvectors_column[0]) != len(projection[0]):
         raise Exception("wrong shape")

     empty_mat = np.array(eigenvectors_column, copy=True)  # this is required for the function call but unused
     # GEMM_2_T transposes the eigenvector
     result = cv2.gemm(projection, eigenvectors_column, 1.0, empty_mat, 0.0, flags=cv2.GEMM_2_T)

     flattened_array = result[0]
     flattened_image = np.hstack(cv2.add(flattened_array, mean))
     flattened_image = np.asarray([np.uint8(num) for num in flattened_image])
     all_rows = []
     for row_index in xrange(image_height):
         row = flattened_image[row_index * image_width: (row_index + 1) * image_width]
         all_rows.append(row)
     image_matrix = np.asarray(all_rows)
     image = normalize_hist(image_matrix)
     return image


 def normalize_hist(face):
     face_as_mat = np.asarray(face)
     equalized_face = cv2.equalizeHist(face_as_mat)
     equalized_face = cv.fromarray(equalized_face)                                                                                                                                                                                 
     return equalized_face
```