# What is the best method to train the faces with FaceRecognizer OpenCV to have the best result?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, face-recognition

Here I say that I have tried many [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html) to implement face recognition in OpenCV 3.2 by using the FaceRecognizer class in face module. But I did not get the accepted result as I wish.

Here I want to ask and I want to know, that what is the best way or what are the conditions to be care off during training and recognizing?

**What I have done to improve the accuracy:**

- Create (at least) 10 faces for training each person in the best quality, size, and angle.
- Try to fit the face in the image.
- Equalize the HIST of the images

And then I have tried all the three face recognizer (EigenFaceRecognizer, FisherFaceRecognizer, LBPHFaceRecognizer), the result all was the same, but the recognition rate was really very low, I have trained only for three persons, but also cannot recognize very well (the fist person was recognized as the second and so on problems).

**Questions:**

- Do the training and the recognition images must be from the same
  camera?
- Do the training images cropped manually (photoshop -> read images then train) or this task
  must be done programmatically (detect-> crop-> resize then train)?
- And what are the best parameters for the each face recognizer `(int num_components, double threshold)`
- And how to set training Algorithm to return -1 when it is an unknown
  person.

Comment: **Q1**: Preferred but not compulsory, cameras must have comparable quality
**Q2**: There would be no difference in both of them, But I would choose to do programmatically, as it would save some of my time.
**Q3**: You can try with the default params in the docs, they worked fine for me
**Q4**: Read the [line 134](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html#eigenfaces-in-opencv) *Happy Eid*

Comment: @ZdaR Thanks! Can you tell me here what is higher threshold means and what lower threshold means, and what is the good value for this? And these parameters are for training or also for recognizing? Because when I trained the data, then I will save it and then in the next time I only load the data. When I load the data, I also must prepare the same parameters as when I trained?

Comment: Can you attach the link of docs, where these terms are referred ?

Comment: @ZdaR Thanks, bro! Happy Eid to you also. The only docs which I went step by step are the link above in the question, the other idea I have gathered from other forums like Stack Overflow and so on, so there is no any exact link. But there was not anything good about the parameters, e.g: what is good for what kind of situation, and also these params are used during training or during recognizing and so on.

Comment: @BahramdunAdil For inspiration also have a look at [Chapter 8 of Mastering OpenCV](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/tree/master/Chapter8_FaceRecognition) - there are some really handy notes on pre-processing faces

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Thanks, sir! It was a good reference.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment, Chapter 8 in Mastering OpenCV provides really helpful tips for pre-processing faces to make aid the recognition process, such as:

- taking a sample only when both eyes are detected (via haar cascade)
- > Geometrical transformation and cropping: This process would include scaling, rotating, and translating the images so that the eyes are aligned, followed by the removal of the forehead, chin, ears, and background from the face image.
- > Separate histogram equalization for left and right sides: This process standardizes the brightness and contrast on both the left- and right-hand sides of the face independently.
- > Smoothing: This process reduces the image noise using a bilateral filter.
- > Elliptical mask: The elliptical mask removes some remaining hair and background from the face image.

I've added a hacky load/save to [my fork of the example code](https://github.com/orgicus/code/blob/master/Chapter8_FaceRecognition/main.cpp#L637), feel free to try it/tweak it as you need it. Currently it's very limited, but it's a start.

Additionally, you should also check [OpenFace and it's DNN face recognizer](https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/demo-3-classifier/).
I haven't played with that yet so can't provide details, but it looks really cool.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I have a question, I think there is something left in the preprocessing.cpp file in line 224, that there is no pass the parameter `scaledWidth` and also there no any default value for this. How to solve this?

Comment: @BahramdunAdil I had a look through the whole chapter example code, but couldn't find `scaledWidth` and I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: `void detectLargestObject(const Mat &img, CascadeClassifier &cascade, Rect &largestObject, int scaledWidth)` I say that in line 224 in the preprocessing.cpp file, why there is no any value for `scaledWidth` you can carefully see again, maybe you will see that.

Comment: I think I see what you mean: the [`detectLargestObject()` call on line 224 in preprocessFace.cpp](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/blob/master/Chapter8_FaceRecognition/preprocessFace.cpp#L224). The function definition is actually in [detectObject.h at line 37](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/blob/master/Chapter8_FaceRecognition/detectObject.h#L37) and you'll notice `scaledWidth` has a default value of 320. If you don't pass a different value when you make the call, the default value will be used.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. Thanks! I am using Java so I am so familiar with C++, I have already translated the code to Java. But now one problem left, which is this `subspaceProject`  function I did not find anywhere even in the OpenCV library, how do you think what is this function.

Comment: `subspaceProject` and `subspaceReconstruct` are missing from the official OpenCV Java API as the [LDA class](http://answers.opencv.org/question/118063/ldasubspaceproject-and-subspacereconstruct-in-java/) isn't available. I haven't tried it myself, but it looks a different OpenCV Java wrapper provides this functionality: [java-cpp presets opencv](http://bytedeco.org/javacpp-presets/opencv/apidocs/org/bytedeco/javacpp/opencv_core.LDA.html). Another option might be porting the functions themselves from [c++](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/lda.cpp#L172)

Comment: Here's a [Python example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19756176/opencv-facerecognition-subspaceproject-and-subspacereconstruct-methods-in-pytho) for reference. It would be great if you could share your progress on github :)

Comment: I did some work, the same time I have detected some problem with that code. #1 the reconstructed face for the Eigenfaces was very different than the image, so the NORM_L2 similarity always return very high value, but the fisher face was a little bit OK. #2 I was wondering although this is a face recognition algorithm and why for a confidence value we need to use the NORM_L2? The face recognition algorithm even cannot calculate the confidence, then how can recognize a face, I think it must not be like, otherwise, the behavior of the recognition algorithm goes under the question. What you think?